# Qt translation is missing for class with tr

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I'm using visual studio + qt plugin for my project. 
Created MyClass inherited from QAbstractTableModel. 
That class is a part of a dll library. 
I've overridden QAbstractTableModel::headerData, added tr("string") inside. 
However tr did not work, no context was created and no name was added to the generated ts file.

Could anyone please help with that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. 
Just forgot to add library which contains my class to ts lupdate / lrelease list.

Answer (score 1):

try calling

```
QObject::tr("string")
```

or add

```
#include <QObject>
```

and call tr directly.

Comment: Tried to do both ways, no effect.

Comment: No, just nothing about my class in the ts file. If add translation manually to ts, it just removes it when regenerates ts.